# Not showing inserted data in DB visualizer

Tags: unit-testing, hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB for unit-testing. I am able to run unit tests successfully.
I have also created a simple utility that starts up HSQLDB, so that I can connect to it by DB visualizer.
As part of booting the DB, this utility runs some script to create a database with some seed data.
However I am not able to see the tables or data in my DB Visualizer client.
Funny thing, the DB Visualizer connects to a DB even if I have not started the said utility, so there shouldn't be a database at all.

I've tried this using both HSQLDB - 1.8.0.10 and 2.3.2, with same result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a HSQLDB server before connecting to it. It seems you are connecting directly to a file: database. When a file: database does not exists, HSQLDB creates itects to a file database. This is what you see when you connect with DBVisualizer.